# Error property undefined in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, properties, undefined

I have a HTMLElement type initialized at the beginning of my component class like this:
My component class:

```html
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Renderer, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JhiEventManager } from 'ng-jhipster';


@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-login-modal',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class JhiLoginModalComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
   
    domElement: HTMLElement;
 

    constructor(
       
        private login1: ElementRef

    ) {
        
    }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.accessDomElement();

    }
    accessDomElement() {
     this.domElement = this.login1.nativeElement.querySelector(`#login123`);
    }
```

My testing class:

```html
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async, inject, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

  describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  
    let comp: JhiLoginModalComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<JhiLoginModalComponent>;
          beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              ............
        }));
        
          beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JhiLoginModalComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            ....
              });
              //MY TEST
                it ('The form login should have the field Nombre', async(() => {
            console.log('lalalalla' + comp.domElement);
            expect(comp.domElement.innerHTML).toContain('Login');
        }));
```

Now I want to test the domElement in a testing class.

But it returns undefined when I print domElement.

My html eleemnt:

```
  <label id="login123" for="username" jhiTranslate="global.form.username">Login</label>
```

I want to test THIS ELEMENT DOMeLEMET WHICH IS OF TYPE HTMLELEMENT.
Do I make an error in injection?? Because it gives me this error:
**Cannot read prperty innerHTMLof undefined and outputs undefined in console.**

Comment: Where is the constructor?

Comment: @Niladri I edited teh question

Comment: Are you sure that an element with the id `login123` exists?

Comment: @kshetline yes sure it is the id of my html label which is on the html file and inserted in the component like this: templateUrl: './login.component.html'

Comment: `domElement = this.login1.nativeElement.querySelector('#login123');` does not access the property of your class. It should be `this.domElement = this.login1.nativeElement.querySelector('#login123');`.

Comment: It gives teh same result @Leon. I have edited my question.

Comment: Do you call `fixture.detectChanges()` somewhere in your test?

Comment: @Leon  if I call it before console.log prints nothing and if after prints lalalaUndefined and the same error.